# How to use Jquery Mobile in Struts 1

Tags: jquery-mobile, struts1

I am developing web application using JSP and struts1. Developing front end using JSTL & Struts tags and Common css class for design. is there any possibility to use jquery mobile in my application. If there how to use it.

Comment: Yes, of course there is. Struts runs on the server; jQuery Mobile runs on the client, so they shouldn't much interfere with each other.

Comment: You use jQuery Mobile in an S1 app like any other web app; they're completely unrelated.